# OSM-based military map

Tags: openstreetmap

Is there an openstreetmap based system that makes it possible to draw something like military symbols?
It should be possible to draw frontline, zones of control, battle events, troops, vehicles and so on. I think, there should be such project, because it would useful for analyzing modern conflicts or even planning historic reconstruction events.

Comment: fictional yes, for security reasons not factual. historical possible see http://opengeofiction.net/#map=5/37.492/56.074 create you own country/island

Comment: Historical Objects http://geschichtskarten.openstreetmap.de/historische_objekte/translate/en/index-en.html using Open Street Map <has drawing tools in the layers at the bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the whole OpenStreetMap stack for that. In fact, all you need is a map background to draw military features on top of it. Try [uMap](http://umap.openstreetmap.fr/en/): it allows drawing lines of different colour and choosing icons for markers. To add custom markers and line types, [fork the project](https://bitbucket.org/yohanboniface/umap).

As for existing OSM-based systems, I haven't seen one yet.

Answer (score 1):

QGIS should fit your needs.

Using QGIS plus OpenStreetMap Plugins by choice, you can eazily create your basic canvas or the target area.

Furthermore adding the TimeManager-Plugin, you can add your military action and even animate it video alike.